# Is it possible to detect when iPhone is turned on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I was wondering if it was possible to detect if an iPhone was turned on (from full shut down, not sleep mode) and then send a notification after it turns on? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: No, its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hook your app up as a SIP service, take heed, this will not pass the app store process and will most likely be rejected if you do not use SIP functionality.  This will get your app starting on boot at least.